# Access Text File inside MVC Controller using SAS string passed from View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage-files, sas-token

My Azure Storage Account has text files stored in a File Share.

In a View, the user selects a file for 'processing', and my JavaScript routine passes the sas (.accessibleUri) up to the Controller function (i.e. Function ProcessDataFile).

The Controller function grabs the sas from the query (Request.Url.Query).

So how do I open and read the file within the Controller function, so that I can process it's contents?  I've tried:

```
        Dim file As New CloudFile(New Uri(fileSasUri(1)))
        ViewBag.ShowMe = file.DownloadText()
```

This, however, throws an exception:

> ErrorMessage
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) --- End of inner exception stack trace

Here's the SAS. Note the final ' is because I wanted to be sure there were no white-space issues, front or back of the string.
[image: SAS string]

Included in my View is the ability to allow the user to Download the file, simply by clicking the Download hyperlink. I know that this is what the SAS is great for: it gives the user the ability to download the file from the View (client page).

It stands to reason that I should be able to have a Controller function do the same thing (access the file for read capability so that I can process it's contents).

However, at this point, I'm thinking of simply using the file name, instead, and using my AzureStorage class to access the file, all over again (on the 2nd trip up). But I'd really like to use the already-assigned SAS token, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Have you verified that the value in `fileSasUri(1)` is EXACTLY what you need it to be?

Comment: An Alert shows me that the .accessibleUri that is passed to the viewer (initially) matches the query that I'm sending back up to the Controller, exactly.  So are you saying that the method I'm using above, should work?

Comment: Thanks Ann L. for replying. I just checked again, comparing the SAS string coming into the View, to the one going back out of the same view (which I'm passing to the new controller function).  They match exactly. I have an AzureStorage class that works great, which grabs all the file info and through a controller function, dumps the file info (name/size) into a View. The user then selects the file he wants, for processing. I then bounce the SAS to a new controller function, where I want to process the contents of the file.

Comment: The sas uri should be in this format `https://{accountname}.file.core.windows.net/{file share name}/{filename}?sv=2017-07-29&sp=r&se=2018-06-02T06%3A44%3A49Z&sr=f&sig={xxxx}`. Check whether your uri can download the file directly in browser.

Comment: @user713723 Not at all an expert on this, but I'm wondering:  your `accessibleUri` has been made XML-safe, with your `&sp=r` looking like `&amp;sp=r`.  Maybe that's the problem: your query string, rather than being a series of key-value pairs separated by `&`, is one key value pair (`sv`) with a really long text value.